# Uri em imagem não está aparecendo

Tags: firebase, react-native

Ola, 
Então, estou fazendo um projeto, e nele preciso que a imagem do usuário apareça logo quando é carregada. Para isso estou usando o firebase storage, e consigo pegar a URL da imagem que preciso, que no caso é esse : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projetotindoar.appspot.com/o/images%2FhAV6dDpbHxgWV9XJnd76gnK2x513?alt=media&token=58815f99-7dfd-440b-8f34-6de363b8f0e5

Porém, utilizando o código abaixo, a imagem não está aparecendo. O que faço?

Código :

```
{/*Foto do Usuario*/}
<View style={styles.fotoUsuario}>
{console.log("URL DA IMAGEM : ",this.state.imgUrl)}
  <Image source={{uri:this.state.imgUrl}}/>
</View>
```

O resultado que aparece no console.log é o mesmo link citado acima. Desde já, agradeço.

Guilherme.

Comment: Adicione como está o estilo, o conteudo do `styles.fotoUsuario`. Já adianto que para que a imagem seja mostrada você deve colocar os valores de altura e largura

Answer (score 1):

A resolução da imagem é muito grande para aparecer na tela do celular. Para 
solucionar, basta adicionar largura e altura no estilo da imagem.

```
<Image
  style={{width: 150, height: 150}}
  source={{uri:'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projetotindoar
    .appspot.com/o/images%2FhAV6dDpbHxgWV9XJnd76gnK2x513?alt=media&token=5881
    5f99-7dfd-440b-8f34-6de363b8f0e5'
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Era exatamente esse o problema. Muito obrigado

Comment: Se a resposta supriu o seu problema, marque-a como certa.